# Subsections of one section do not appear in TOC (LaTeX beamer mode)

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I'm trying to prepare a presentation using LaTeX's beamer mode. For some reason the subsections of my last section do not show up in the TOC.

Here is my MWE (incl. all the packages I'm using):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,compress]{beamer}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel} % language listed last is default setting
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsbsy}
\usepackage{nccmath} % includes {fleqn} environment
\usepackage{bbm} % includes \mathbbm{} symbols 

\usepackage{braket} % Bra-Ket notation in quantum mechanics 

\usepackage{helvet} % font set to "helvetica"

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{microtype} 

\parindent=0mm % indent to indicate new paragraph prohibited

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{chapter}
\makeatother % section count set to 0 when new chapter begins

\usepackage{listliketab}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{isotope} 
\usepackage{extarrows}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile} % changes the algorithm to check for known file extensions instead of using the first dot "." to find the file extension as conducted by "graphicx" and also "graphcis"

\DeclareMathSizes{12}{9}{7}{5}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure} 

\let\origitem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{\normalfont\origitem}
\newcommand{\bolditem}{\normalfont\bfseries\origitem}

\newcommand{\eqqcolon}{\mathrel{=\!\!\mathop:}}
\newcommand{\coloneqq}{\mathrel{\mathop:\!\!=}}

\usepackage{pdfpages} 


% following content recommended for LaTeX beamer mode

\title{\textbf{Title}}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author} 
\institute{Institute}
\date{\scriptsize{Date}}


\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % default navigation symbols hidden
\usetheme{Berlin}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]

\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}    {\hfill\insertsectionheadnumber.~\insertsectionhead}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{\color{structure!50}\hfill\insertsectionheadnumber.~\insertsectionhead}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\inserttocsectionnumber.~\inserttocsection}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\small \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
\end{frame}
} % display table of contents with current section higlighted automatically


\begin{document}

{ % to delimit a block (changes apply for this block only)
\makeatletter % to change template
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]
\def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[default]
\def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\footheight}}
\makeatother
\frame{\titlepage} 
}

{ % to delimit a block (changes apply for this block only)
\makeatletter % to change template
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]
\def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}}
\makeatother
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents} \small \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
}


\section{Section 1}

\subsection{Subsection 1.1}

\subsection{Subsection 1.2}

\subsection{Subsection 1.3}

\subsection{Subsection 1.4}


\section{Section 2}

\subsection{Subsection 2.1}

\subsection{Subsection 2.2}


\section{Section 3}

\subsection{Subsection 3.1}

\subsection{Subsection 3.2}

\subsection{Subsection 3.3}

\subsection{Subsection 3.4}


\section{Section 4}


\section{Section 5}

\subsection{Subsection 5.1}

\subsection{Subsection 5.2}

\end{document}
```

I can't seem to find my mistake. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure exactly what happens, but if you add some content in the last subsection e.g. `\begin{frame}abc\end{frame}`, it seems to work fine.

Comment: You're right. Thank you :) That actually solves the problem for me. However, if anyone happens to know why this is happening I'd be glad to hear it!

Comment: I think it is because \subsection (unlike \section) doesn't actually typeset anything and so unless something afterwards is typeset, somehow nothing gets output at all. (But I'm not sure about this.) I'm confused by your source, though, because I thought that \makeatletter and \makeatother could only be used in the preamble but you are using them in the document itself. (Although I'm not sure why you use them, I don't get errors either.)

Comment: \makeatletter and \makeatother are used to change the beamer template that is used throughout the entire document. changes that are defined between \makeatletter and \makeatother apply for what is typeset inside the curly brackets {} only. eliminate \makeatletter and \makeatother and you will see that the titlepage and the TOC are not properly aligned (regarding vertical spacing).

Answer (score 2):

For sections to show up in the TOC, they must be added to the `.toc` file. It seems that for this to happen, it is necessary for something to be typeset after the relevant section command. Because `\section` is set up to *typeset* a version of the table of contents, `\section` will always add the section to the TOC. In the case of `\subsection`, however, this isn't the case so for these to be added, something must be explicitly added after the relevant command. As  Torbjørn T. points out, this could be a frame containing content. But it could be another `\section` command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,compress]{beamer}

% following content recommended for LaTeX beamer mode

\title{\textbf{Title}}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}
\date{\scriptsize{Date}}


\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % default navigation symbols hidden
\usetheme{Berlin}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]

\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}    {\hfill\insertsectionheadnumber.~\insertsectionhead}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{\color{structure!50}\hfill\insertsectionheadnumber.~\insertsectionhead}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\inserttocsectionnumber.~\inserttocsection}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\small \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
\end{frame}
} % display table of contents with current section higlighted automatically


\begin{document}

\frame[plain]{\titlepage}

{ % to delimit a block (changes apply for this block only)
\makeatletter % to change template
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]
\def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}}
\makeatother
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents} \small \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
}

\section{Section 1}

\subsection{Subsection 1.1}

\subsection{Subsection 1.2}

\subsection{Subsection 1.3}

\subsection{Subsection 1.4}


\section{Section 2}

\subsection{Subsection 2.1}

\subsection{Subsection 2.2}


\section{Section 3}

\subsection{Subsection 3.1}

\subsection{Subsection 3.2}

\subsection{Subsection 3.3}

\subsection{Subsection 3.4}


\section{Section 4}


\section{Section 5}

\subsection{Subsection 5.1}

\subsection{Subsection 5.2}

\section{Section 6}

\end{document}
```

[image: TOC]